# ResourceDictionary organization

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, resourcedictionary, code-organization

There are two decent online resources on this topic that I know of, [XAML Guidelines](http://www.cookingwithxaml.com/content/xamlguidelines/xamlGuidelinesDraft0.pdf) and [this less complete one](http://projekt202.com/blog/2010/xaml-organization/).

And I still don't quite get it!

For example, say I have two projects:

1. Wpf.ControlLibrary.proj
2. Wpf.App.proj

Inside Wpf app I have three resources that work together to form a uniform way for different views to provide error feedback and close. Two of those resources are made available via a DataTemplate:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="EditedStateIndicator.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="CloseCrossToggleButton.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<DataTemplate x:Key="SatelliteViewClosePanelStyle" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource CloseCrossButtonStyle}"  />
        <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource EditedStateIndicatorStyle}"  />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

This in turn is made available in "SatelliteView.ResourceLibrary.xaml":

```
<!-- ##Satellite View Library-->
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <ResourceDictionary Source="SatelliteViewClosePanel.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="InlineBorder.xaml" />

</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Which in turn is made available in a "ControlLibrary.ResourceLibrary.xaml"

```
<!-- ##Master Control Library reference-->
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    ...
    <ResourceDictionary Source="CustomControlStyles/SatelliteViewStyles/ResourceLibrary.xaml" />

    ...

</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

And then consumed in the Wpf.App project, literally App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Wpf.ControlLibrary;component/ResourceLibrary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

Inside the app is a view which uses some content that also needs access to the control library:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   Source="pack://application:,,,/SWpf.ControlLibrary;component/ResourceLibrary.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<DataTemplate x:Key="AvatarEditingControlTemplate">

    ...

</DataTemplate>
```

## Ok, so What is your Question?

1. Given that the DataTemplate requires "ControlLibrary.ResourceLibrary" or throws an error, what good is having it available in App.Resources? I thought app resources should make all resources available to the app?
2. How might I better organize the rresources shown here, or is this a decent approach? Any other good links on the topic that I missed? Do most non-trivial projects require some code to get some sort of shared resource library going?

Cheers,
Berryl